# У меня получается 0 при выводе на консоль. Где ошибка? Смотрю примеры так же решаются

Tags: java

```
public static int convertToSeconds(int hour)
{
    int sec = hour / 3600;
    return sec;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println ((convertToSeconds(34)));
    System.out.println ((convertToSeconds(15)));    
}
```

Comment: Код как то криво получилось оформить. Где бы справку почитать?

Comment: Спасибо за правку кода :)

Comment: справка по форматированию: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уверен, что имеется в виду

```
int sec = hour * 3600;
              ^^^
```

Иначе это выражение `hour / 3600` всегда будет равно 0 при заданных аргументах, так как имеет место целочисленная арифметика.

Comment: Спасибо :D Как то глупо вышло задавать подобные вопросы.

Comment: @HelloGoogle Ничего страшного. Бывает.:)

Comment: @HelloGoogle, если ответ удодвлетворяет полностью, отметьте его, как правильный